# Using PHP to set checked option on a radio button based on data from database. BUT it only works on some data

Tags: php, html

Here is the code snippet, which is inside a form:

```
<fieldset>

<!-- for each radio button, PHP code used to check IF $id==value 
     to determine what should be checked. -->
<div class="newrow">
    <label>Status:</label>
    <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="active" value="active" <?php echo ($status_id==1)?'checked':'' ?> name="status">
        <label for="active">Active</label>

        <input type="radio" id="on-leave" value="leave" <?php echo ($status_id==2)?'checked':'' ?>name="status">
        <label for="on-leave">On Leave</label>

        <input type="radio" id="terminated" value="terminated" <?php echo ($status_id==3)?'checked':'' ?>name="status">
        <label for="terminated">Terminated</label>
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="newrow">
    <label>Eligible for rehire?</label>
    <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="yes" value="yes" <?php echo ($rehire_id==1)?'checked':'' ?>name="rehire">
        <label for="yes" class="radio_label">Yes</label>

        <input type="radio" id="no" value="no" <?php echo ($rehire_id==2)?'checked':'' ?> name="rehire">
        <label for="no" class="radio_label">No</label>
    </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
```

The first thing I want to point out is that in the first row, I decide what to check based on `$status_id`.  For this row if `$status_id == 1`, the first radio button is checked.  BUT if it equals 2 or 3, nothing gets checked.

But in the second row, I decide what to check based on $rehire_id.  If `$rehire == 2`, the second button is checked, BUT NOTHING happens if it equals 1.

WHAT is going on here?  Any ideas?

Comment: Fix the HTML, look at what is generated using the browser "page Source" option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no space between `checked` and the `name` tag in the cases where it's not working.

When `$status_id==2` is true

```
value="leave" <?php echo ($status_id==2)?'checked':'' ?>name="status">
```

will output

```
value="leave" checkedname="status">
```

instead of what you expected

```
value="leave" checked name="status">
```

Add a space before each `name=`